# After completing Validation on input function won't link to the next .html

Tags: javascript, html

I created a part of the simple website with a register page I created a validation (.js) for both and wanted to validate the input on the form so after i completed the validation criteria and fill all the input it supposed to link or open the next page (it's login page if you are in the register.html). The problem is if i don't include href to link it, it won't open the next page but the validation was successful but if i include href the validation was skipped and it instantly opens the next page which is login.html after i click on the Register button. How to put validation on the Register button so it validates the input and open the next page at the same time? (A message for a successful registration after that is also better). Here is the code for register and the register validation.

This is called registersraboet.html for the Register page.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register Sraboet</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
 href="css/register.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery- 
latest.min.js"></script>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1.0">

</head>
<body>

<div class="headerregister">

    <img src="assets/logo.png">

</div>  


<div class="containerregister">

    <form action="" id="rgs_form">

        <div id="err_msg"></div>

        <label><b>Email</b></label><br>
        <input type="email" placeholder="masukkan email 
anda" id="emailrgs"><br>

        <label><b>Username</b></label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="masukkan nama 
anda" id="usernamergs"><br>

        <label><b>Password</b></label><br>
        <input type="password" placeholder="masukkan 
password anda" id="passwordrgs"><br>

        <label><b>ID Number</b></label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="masukkan nomor 
KTP anda" id="KTPrgs"><br>

        <label><b>Phone Number</b></label><br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="masukkan nomor 
telepon anda" id="phonergs"><br>

            <div class="termsnprivacy">

                <p>By creating an account you agree to 
our <a href="#">Terms & Privacy</a></p> 

            </div>

            <div class="registerbtn">

                <button type="button" 
onclick="validatergs()">Register</button><br>
            </div>

            <div class="alreadyakun">

                <br><p>Sudah Punya Akun? Silahkan <a 
href="loginsraboet.html">Login</a></p>

            </div>

    </form>
</div>

<div class="footerregister">

    <div class="copyrightfooter">

            <label for="Copyright">Copyright &copy; 
Sraboet 2020</label>

    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" 
src="js/validationregister.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is called validationregister.js for the validation in register.

```
var err = document.getElementById('err_msg');

function validatergs(){
var email = document.getElementById('emailrgs').value;   
var username = 
document.getElementById('usernamergs').value;
var password = 
document.getElementById('passwordrgs').value;
var ktp = document.getElementById('KTPrgs').value;
var phones = document.getElementById('phonergs').value; 

if(email == ""){
    err.innerHTML = "Email harus diisi!"
}

else if(username == ""){
    err.innerHTML = "Nama harus diisi!"
}

else if(password == ""){
    err.innerHTML = "Password harus diisi!"
}

else if(ktp == ""){
    err.innerHTML = "Nomor ktp harus diisi!"
}

else if(!+(ktp)){
    err.innerHTML = "nomor ktp harus angka!";
}

else if(phones == ""){
    err.innerHTML = "Nomor telepon harus diisi!"
}

else if(!+(phones)){
    err.innerHTML = "Nomor telepon harus angka!";
}

else {
    a.href = "loginsraboet.html";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the right way to write it. First you get the a node, use getelementByclass or some other method to trigger the node click() method such as let a= document.getelementbyid (#a);next  a.click ()

Comment: I'm trying the method you suggested but it seems that i get a hard time to comprehend on how to use a node that i created. May i ask for a detail code structure on that part? Sorry, i'm still learning the basic of HTML.

Comment: Update : I have found another solution using location.replace() at my .js, the validation and the link worked. Is this method effective to use?

Comment: because that way I suggested is more common and you will meet similar scenario that appear in trggiering downing file.

Comment: i guess i will try with the common approach you suggested, i will implement it by using nodes then.